# How to make second mac a trusted contact?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, airdrop

I have two MBP 2016 and i used to have them set as trusted, meaning on airdrop If i would set contacts only it could see the other, now I have to select everyone instead. How can I make it a contact of each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the core feature of handoff which also goes by the name continuity. To enable this, just sign into iCloud on both Mac with the exact same Apple ID.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681

At this point Safari browser tab handoff and other supporting application handoff, clipboards synchronization, as well as unprompted automatic AirDrop permissions is enabled.

- sometimes the authentication can be stuck so log out and log in or restart both machines If you need to troubleshoot things once you’re signed in.
- Bluetooth and Wi-Fi need to be turned on for this to work but it shouldn’t matter whether you’re connected to a Wi-Fi network or even the same Wi-Fi network.